# linux : during downloading anaconda jupyter i got these errors

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

```
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/aman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
     status = self.run(options, args)
   File "/home/aman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run     prefix=options.prefix_path,
   File "/home/aman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install     **kwargs
   File "/home/aman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install     self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
   File "/home/aman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files     isolated=self.isolated,
   File "/home/aman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files     clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
   File "/home/aman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber     shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile     with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst: IOError: [Errno 13] 
Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_scandir.so'
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo`?

Comment: Use ```sudo``` before commad of downloading

Comment: try sudo su and then conda install jupyter

Comment: There are a hundred questions where the answer is "use sudo".

Answer (score 0):

This is related to permission, hence you need to be sudoer or super user.

Try your command with `sudo` prefix.

```
sudo <YOURCOMMAND>
```